# Help dealing with Async sleep for "Simulated Typing" effect

Tags: async

I am trying to build a function, that takes a body of text from a buffer or a file, and "simulates typing" in another buffer. This will serve me towards recording programming videos where the code appears to be written in real-time.

The main issue I am dealing with is the delay which needs to happen between each character printed.  I have tried using timers such as `run-at-time` and `async-start` with `sleep-for` events.

`run-at-time` is printing every character from the string after the chosen delay, despite being inside a `dolist`.

I am quite a noob on Elisp, maybe someone could give me a hand? I am using Spacemacs. If someone is wondering, the effect that I want to achieve would be something similar of the youtuber Biskwit, but much simpler of course. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SktXhGElf7w)

Comment: For that use, recording programming videos, do you really need the typing to be async? I'd just use `sit-for` and make it synchronous. This is the approach in the built-in `animate` library (try `M-x animate-birthday-present`), for example. It's also the approach in [Andrea Rossetti's `teletype` library](https://github.com/thesoftwarebin/the-emacs-software-bin/blob/master/teletype/teletype.el) which you might even be able to use as is.

Comment: The question is too broad, and so risks being deleted. Instead of asking for general help designing and implementing what you want, please ask specific questions that invite specific answers. In this case, for example, maybe show (code for) what you tried using `run-at-time` etc., and point to a specific (code) problem you ran into. Post separate questions for separate, specific problems or questions you have.

Comment: You say "I have tried using timers ..." but you don't say what was not working with them.